# Cocoapos error - [!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Non-HTTP proxy URI

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am getting

> [!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL:
> `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: Non-HTTP proxy URI:

error during `pod install` when i am trying to run a flutter project.

https proxy is in place on terminal using bash profile.

Also tried to add `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` in podfile but receives same error with this URL.

Comment: those who are struggling with such proxy error, please be aware that even though the URLs mentioned above are https, it may need http proxy to work. I have changed proxy from https to http and got rid of this error. But I am getting new error now which says '[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: execution expired', so not totally sure about which proxy to use.

Answer (score 9):

Disabling IPV6 fixes this.

To disable IPV6 on Mac OS X, do the following:

1. Open System Preferences and click the Network icon.
2. Select the network you are using - It will usually be labeled Wi-Fi.
3. Click the Advanced.. button.
4. Click the TCP/IP tab.
5. Select the Configure IPv6 drop-down menu and set it to Link-local only.
6. Click the OK button.

[Source](https://support.blindsidenetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050168052-How-to-disable-IPV6)

Comment: I can't believe this worked for me. The error started showing for no reason.
No git diff, no `pod deintegrate`.
Thanks you!

Comment: Wow, this worked for me as well. Thanks. I had the following error: `Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: execution expired`

Answer (score 1):

The error was related to proxy configuration for me. For flutter work, I have set below proxies and everything worked fine,

1. Terminal proxy
2. Git proxy

Used below configuration to set terminal proxy,

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy-server:port"
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

and below to git proxy,

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy-server:port
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy-server:port
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal and type **cd ios** for access ios where available pod file.
And then type **arch -x86_64 pod update** and press enter.
Now all ok, you can run your application.
(Work for me 'Mac m1')

Comment: not working for me. still same error

Comment: You have to edit podfile where ios version 9.0 in comment. Now comment out this line and edit with 14.0
Then follow up.

Comment: that doesn't seem related to error. want my app to support iOS 12.0 above and same reflected in podfile.

Answer (score 0):

The link https://cdn.cocoapods.org does not work correctly, I had to change the source in `ios/Podfile` as described in the code below:

1. Change source in `ios/Podfile`

```bash
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

2. Clean your project

```bash
flutter clean
```

3. Install referenced packages

```bash
flutter pub get
```

4. Run the app

---

The error can also come from a package which requires a version higher than `'9.0'` in this case it is necessary to uncomment the line `# platform :ios, '9.0'` and to pass for example to version `'12.0'` according to the version requested by the package.